# jquery input focus out дочерний элемент

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

Есть input с ajax поиском.

```html
<div>
  <input type="text">
  <button>Поиск</button>
  <div class="tip">Тут результаты</div>
</div>
```

input.keyup стоит событие на поиск.

```js
input.focusout(function() {
});
```

Это событие скрывает tip. Но при клике на tip - фокус снимается и по ссылке не перейти - он закрывается. Как это исправить?

Comment: Как насчет использовать таймаут, чтобы tip закрывался не сразу?

Comment: А если пользователь просто кликнет на tip, не перейдя по ссылке

Comment: Тогда он все равно закроется по таймауту.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить отсрочку скрытия tip, как-то так (скроется через 800 миллисекунд):

```
input.focusout(function() {
   $("#tip").delay(800).hide();
});
```

Comment: setTimeout(function(){$("#tip").hide();}, 500);